# How can we configure our VSCode to format C code as per our custom coding standard?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-formatting

How can we configure our VSCode to format C code as per our custom coding standard?

Formatting rules like -

1. Initial indentation is 4 spaces, next indentation is a tab, and one
   more level of indentation is tab+4 spaces, another level is 2 tabs
   and goes on.
2. And the opening braces to be on the same line as the if or for
   statement?
3. How the indentation of the statement in the next line should be. Whether the statement inside `if`
   statement should be indented or just be in the same column alignment as the if statement.
4. And so many other coding style formats.

When I was using Eclipse, I was able to create my custom profile and make all the necessary changes inside it like that -

[image]